# Bootstrap 3 vertical align text to ionicon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align an ionicon icon and text to its side in a vertical way inside a button using Bootstrap 3.

I want the text to be vertically aligned to the center of the button with the icon also vertically aligned.

The default seems to align the icon and the text using their lowest points.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
   <a href="/signout" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger sign-out">
      <i class="ion-power ion-fw"></i>
      <span class="menu-label">Sign Out</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

My CSS is:

```
.main-header .navbar .dropdown-menu li a.sign-out {
   color: #fff !important;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

.ion-fw {
    width: 1.28571429em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

My CSS targets the pair OK as their colors are correct. I have tried padding and margins on `.menu-label` but that moves the text and icon.

How do I adjust the text to the middle of the icon's height? Thanks!

Example:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried applying a negative value to the top margin of the text element?

Comment: Hi @Christian Hill, yes I have and it is not playing ball. This should be straight forward but it has beaten me so far.

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
 .ion-fw {
    width: 1.28571429em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

to this

```
.ion-fw {
    width: 1.28571429em;
    text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

`vertical-align` works on elements in the same container and so must be applied to the contents...not the parent element.

```css
.ion-fw {
  width: 1.28571429em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
  <a href="/signout" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger sign-out">
    <i class="ion-power ion-fw"></i>
    <span class="menu-label">Sign Out</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Paulie_D awesome, thanks! But in your example the text is now too high. It does not seem to center the two side by side. Is there a way to do this regardless of font sizes for each the icon and the text (my icon is slightly bigger in size than the text.

Comment: You could try putting vertical align on the `span` instead [https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/ojbqd918/](https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/ojbqd918/)and, perhaps, instead of `middle` try `baseline`. Experiment but if you're using different font sizes there may not be a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```css
.ion-fw {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 1.4em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
  <a href="/signout" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger sign-out">
    <i class="ion-power ion-fw"></i>
    <span class="menu-label">Sign Out</span>
  </a>
</div>
```